# What is the KQL Syntax to use WebId managed property to restrict the search for particular sub sites by passing the WebId in the QueryText?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, search-results, kql

I want to restrict the search for some sub sites in my SharePoint 2010 environment.
I want to use WebId managed property which represents the GUID of the sub site.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new scope in SharePoint center administration->Manage service applications->search service application->Scope, create rules to set the property query with "WebId".

In the search result web part, select the relevant scope for results.

Comment: I have developed custom search using KQL so I need to pass the WebId in the QueryText of the KQL.